# Using RegEx to Uppercase [variables]

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# string extension that needs to take a string and replace all the [variables] into [VARIABLES], but am not sure where to begin.

```
Source: Hi [name] how are you [other]?
Result: Hi [NAME] how are you [OTHER]?
```

Here's my boilerplate:

```
    public static string VariablesToUpperCase(this string input)
    {
        string pattern = @"\[\w+\]";
        string replacement = "??????";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        return rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 public static string VariablesToUpperCase(this string input)
    {
        string pattern = @"\[\w+\]";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        return rgx.Replace(input, (m) => { return m.ToString().ToUpper(); });
    }
```

I made a change to your pattern. You need to escape the brackets, otherwise you are just matching a character class of a single word character or a plus sign.

To do the uppercasing, we are using the Regex.Replace overload that takes a MatchEvaluator. It gets called for each match and replaces it with the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

```
    public static string VariablesToUpperCase(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"\[\w+\]", delegate (Match match)
        {
            string v = match.ToString();
            return v.ToUpper();
        });
    }
```